# Definition of tree structure in Lisp

Tags: tree, lisp, common-lisp

From the Common Lisp HyperSpec glossary:

> [tree](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/26_glo_t.htm#tree) n. 1. a binary recursive data structure made up of conses and
>   atoms: the conses are themselves also trees (sometimes called
>   "subtrees" or "branches"), and the atoms are terminal nodes (sometimes
>   called leaves). Typically, the leaves represent data while the
>   branches establish some relationship among that data. 2. in general,
>   any recursive data structure that has some notion of "branches" and
>   leaves.
>
> [tree structure](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/26_glo_t.htm#tree_structure) n. (of a tree) the set of conses that make up the tree.
>   Note that while the car[1b] component of each such cons is part of the
>   tree structure, the objects that are the cars of each cons in the tree
>   are not themselves part of its tree structure unless they are also
>   conses.

The last sentence in the definition of tree structure raises a question, which is, can the same be said about cdrs too?

Use of the word binary in the definition of "tree" seems to suggest that there is no difference between car vs cdr for the purposes of trees, but then the definition of "tree structure" seems to treat cars special, so I am confused.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Short answer

> The last sentence in the definition of tree structure raises a
> question, which is, can the same be said about cdrs too?

I think the answer is "yes."  There's a similar definition for *list structure* with almost identical wording.   There's more potential for confusion about in list structure about whether the value of a car of a cons is part of the list structure, since questions can arise about, e.g., "what does it mean to replace X in the list (X (X) Y)?"  The cdr isn't really in question much, since the cdr is the *rest* of the list;  it's sort of obviously part of the list structure.

For *tree structure*, I think that there's less ambiguity;  cons in the car or the cdr is a subtree.  The definitions of *tree structure* and *list structure* are almost identical in places, and I wouldn't be surprised if someone wrote the definition for *list structure*, and then copied it for *tree structure*, making the minimal number of changes necessary to be accurate.  That would leave the bit about cars in there, even though the question that it answers probably wouldn't arise in practice.

### Longer answer

Let's look at the definition of *list structure* and compare:

> [list structure](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/26_glo_l.htm#list_structure) n. (of a list) the set of conses that make up the list.
> Note that while the car component of each such cons is part of the
> list structure, the objects that are elements of the list (i.e., the
> objects that are the cars of each cons in the list) are not
> themselves part of its list structure, even if they are conses, except
> in the (circular) case where the list actually contains one of its
> tails as an element. (The list structure of a list is sometimes
> redundantly referred to as its ``top-level list structure'' in order
> to emphasize that any conses that are elements of the list are not
> involved.)

Note the specific places where these differ:

> (list structure) Note that while the car component of each such cons is part of the
> list structure, the objects that are elements of the list (i.e., the
> objects that are the cars of each cons in the list) are not
> themselves part of its list structure, even if they are conses.

> (tree structure) Note that while the car component of each such cons is part of the
> tree structure, the objects that are the cars of each cons in the tree
> are not themselves part of its tree structure unless they are also
> conses.

That means that in

```
(1 (2) 3) == (cons 1 (cons (cons 2 nil) (cons 3 nil)))
```

there are *three* cons cells in the list structure, and *four* cons cells in the tree structure.

Where does this actually matter?  It becomes important to define these terms precisely so that the specification can easily define what parts of a list or tree are traversed or modified by particular functions.

#### nsubst can modify tree structure

For instance, the functions [**nsubst** and friends](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_substc.htm), whose documentation states:

> nsubst, nsubst-if, and nsubst-if-not might alter the [*tree structure*](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/26_glo_t.htm#tree_structure) of
> tree.

A specific definition of tree structure allows us to understand what things may and may not be changed by **nsubst**.

> [tree structure](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/26_glo_t.htm#tree_structure) n. (of a tree) the set of conses that make up the tree.
> Note that while the car component of each such cons is part of the
> tree structure, the objects that are the cars of each cons in the tree
> are not themselves part of its tree structure unless they are also
> conses.

So, what this is telling us is that for any cons cell *x* in the tree, **nsubst** might do **(setf (car x) …)**, so that the **(car x)** might be something different later on, but it won't modify the actual object that would be returned by **(car x)** (unless it's a cons, of course).  This could be important in cases where the value of **(car x)** is an object that might have trees inside of it.  So for instance, **nsubst** won't descend into vectors, but it will replace vectors:

```
(let* ((l (list 1 2 3))     ; a list
       (v (vector 0 l 4))   ; a vector that contains the list (and other elements)
       (tree (cons l v)))   ; a tree containing the list and the vector
  (nsubst 'x l tree))       ; replace the list in the tree with X
;=> (X . #(0 (1 2 3) 4))    ; nsubst doesn't descend into the vector, because it's
                            ; not tree structure
```

#### delete-duplicates can modify list structure

On the other hand [**delete-duplicates**](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_rm_dup.htm) will only modify list structure:

> delete-duplicates, when sequence is a list, is permitted to setf any
> part, car or cdr, of the top-level list structure in that sequence.
> When sequence is a vector, delete-duplicates is permitted to change
> the dimensions of the vector and to slide its elements into new
> positions without permuting them to produce the resulting vector.

Answer (score 3):

> Note that while the car[1b] component of each such cons is part of the
>   tree structure, the objects that are the cars of each cons in the tree
>   are not themselves part of its tree structure unless they are also
>   conses.

As far as I can see, author of this definition tries to draw the line between sturcture of tree itself and its objects. So it states that only conses can make up structure of tree.

Consider this example:

```
(1 2 (3 "string") 4)
```

While object `"string"` is part of the tree (and it is `car` of `("string")`), it is not part of tree structure, because strings don't consist of cons cells.

I suppose author of the definition had in mind proper lists, because for them every element is `car`:

```
(cons "foo" (cons "bar" (cons "baz" nil)))
;     ^car^       ^car^       ^car^
```

`cdr` rather defines structure of tree in case of proper list.

But you also could consider the following as tree:

```
("foo" . "bar")
```

In this case `cdr` would not be part of tree structure.

Comment: **I suppose author of the definition had in mind proper lists** I don't think that's the case.  The glossary also defines *list structure*, where the elements of the list are the cars of the conses of the list structure. I think that these terms are included primarily to make it clear what structures are traversed and can be modified by standard functions.  E.g., if you replace X with Y in the tree **(X (X) #(X)))** you get **(Y (Y) #(X)))**, but if you replace in the list **(X (X) #(X)))**, you get **(Y (X) #(X)))**.  It's easiest to describe the modification in terms of tree/list structures.

Comment: @Joshua, Well, OP's question was: "can the same (`car` component of each cons is part of the tree structure, the objects that are the cars of each cons in the tree are not themselves part of its tree structure) be said about cdrs too". So in my answer I focus on differences between `car` and `cdr` in tree structure. In proper lists (and thus trees) every object (atom) is always `car` of cons, and I think that's why author of the definition emphasize cars.

Comment: @Joshua, I just don't see why author of the definition doesn't state the same about `cdr`s then. I may be wrong.

Comment: That's a good point.  To be honest, though, I wouldn't be surprised if the definition of one of these terms was written (maybe the one for lists) and then copied with minimal edits for the other.  The wording is almost identical and, as you say, since it's kind of *obvious* that the *cdr* of a list is part of the list structure, it's only whether a "sublist" in the car is part of the list structure that's in question.  So while I think that "I suppose author of the definition had in mind proper lists" isn't quite right, it may well be the case that "the definition emphasizes this because it…

Comment: …was based on a similar definition for lists, where the emphasis on cars made more sense.