# Changing copies of lists in LISP

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, pass-by-reference

In LISP, I have a function that is passed a list. I would like to change an element of this list without changing the original list. Normally, I would use `copy-list` to create the local copy of the list which I will change, but this doesn't seem to be working:

```
CL-USER> (defun test (item)
    (let ((copy (copy-list item)))
         (setf (nth 0 (nth 0 (nth 0 copy))) t)
         (print item)
         (print copy)))

CL-USER> (defparameter item `(((NIL NIL) (NIL NIL) (NIL NIL))
                     ((NIL NIL NIL) (NIL NIL NIL))
                     ((3 3) (NIL NIL))))

CL-USER> (test item)
(((T NIL) (NIL NIL) (NIL NIL)) ((NIL NIL NIL) (NIL NIL NIL)) ((3 3) (NIL NIL))) 
(((T NIL) (NIL NIL) (NIL NIL)) ((NIL NIL NIL) (NIL NIL NIL)) ((3 3) (NIL NIL))) 
(((T NIL) (NIL NIL) (NIL NIL)) ((NIL NIL NIL) (NIL NIL NIL)) ((3 3) (NIL NIL)))
CL-USER> item
(((T NIL) (NIL NIL) (NIL NIL)) ((NIL NIL NIL) (NIL NIL NIL)) ((3 3) (NIL NIL)))
```

As you can see, the value of `item` was changed by `test` even though I copied the list into a local variable and changed the local copy. This seems to be a symptom of using `nth`. If I use a single call of `car` rather than the repeated call to `nth`, the function works as expected and the `item` is unchanged after the call.

Why does `nth` behave like this and how can I continue to use `nth` without altering the value passed to `test`?

I am using Common Lisp.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the difference between a deep copy and a shallow copy?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/184710/what-is-the-difference-between-a-deep-copy-and-a-shallow-copy)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Short answer: use cl:copy-tree

You probably want to copy the whole tree with [**copy-tree**](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_cp_tre.htm).  The copy made by **copy-list** only generates new "backbone";  you get a new list, but with the *same* elements.  **Copy-tree** will copy all the cons-tree structure that makes up the tree.

### Long answer: list structure vs. tree structure

The background here is referenced in the documentation.  From the HyperSpec:

> #### Function [COPY-LIST](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_cp_lis.htm)
>
> Only the [list structure](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/26_glo_l.htm#list_structure) of list is copied; the elements of the
>   resulting list are the same as the corresponding elements of the given
>   list.

That glossary entry for *list structure* is important:

> list structure n. (of a list) the set of conses that make up the list.
>   Note that while the car component of each such cons is part of the
>   list structure, the objects that are elements of the list (i.e., the
>   objects that are the cars of each cons in the list) are not
>   themselves part of its list structure, even if they are conses, except
>   in the (circular) case where the list actually contains one of its
>   tails as an element. (The list structure of a list is sometimes
>   redundantly referred to as its "top-level list structure" in order
>   to emphasize that any conses that are elements of the list are not
>   involved.)

As a very simple example, we can exploit the fact that ***print-circle*** will show us common substructure:

```
CL-USER> (setf *print-circle* t)
T

CL-USER> (let ((l '((a b c) (d e f))))
           (list l (copy-list l)))
;=> ((#1=(A B C) #2=(D E F)) (#1# #2#))

CL-USER> (let ((l '((a b c) (d e f))))
           (list l (copy-tree l)))
;=> (((A B C) (D E F)) ((A B C) (D E F)))
```

The HyperSpec entry on **copy-tree** doesn't link to *tree structure*, but there *is* a glossary entry:

> [tree structure](http://www.smbc-comics.com) n. (of a tree) the set of conses that make up the
>   tree. Note that while the car component of each such cons is part
>   of the tree structure, the objects that are the cars of each cons
>   in the tree are not themselves part of its tree structure unless they
>   are also conses.

That second sentence is a bit strange, but it's probably just in there as a minimally adjusted copy and paste of the *list structure* entry.  See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25059159/1281433) to [Definition of tree structure in Lisp](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25052371/1281433) for a bit more about that.

Comment: This is really a confusing language: "while the car component of each such cons is part of the list structure, the objects that are the cars of each cons in the list are not themselves part of its list structure"!!!