# Argument to lisp function changed despite creating a copy

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I have created a function to randomly select a 'bit' out of a nested list, e.g., `((1 0 0 1) (1 1 1 1) (0 1 0 1))`, and then flip it.  If it is a one, make it a zero and *vice versa*. The function works well, but I have discovered that it mutates the original argument despite my making a copy. Here is the function, the two writes at the end demonstrate this problem. If I pass `((1 1 1 1))` to this, I expect to see this original value printed by `(write DNA-seq)` but instead the original is modified, so `(write DNA-seq)` and `(write CDNA-seq)` print the same thing.

```
(defun rand-mutate (DNA-seq)
  (let ((CDNA-seq (copy-list DNA-seq)))
    (let ((gene (random-range 0 (length CDNA-seq))))
      (let ((base (random-range 0 (length (nth gene CDNA-seq)))))
        (cond ((= (nth base (nth gene CDNA-seq)) 0) (setf (nth base (nth gene CDNA-seq)) 1))
              (t (setf (nth base (nth gene CDNA-seq)) 0))) (write DNA-seq)(write CDNA-seq)))))
```

Comment: You may find [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26792893/1281433) to [Changing copies of lists in LISP](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26791982/1281433) useful.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`copy-list` is a *shallow* copy, it only copies the outermost list, not the lists that each element refers to. Use `copy-tree` to perform a *deep* copy.

```
(defvar list '((1 0 0 1)))
(defvar list-copy (copy-list list))
(defvar list-copy-tree (copy-tree list))
(eq list list-copy) => NIL
(eq (car list) (car list-copy)) => T
(eq (car list) (car list-copy-tree)) => NIL
```

Comment: Thank you for the swift answer, I suspected it would be something simple I was missing. That solved it!